# Value error in windows phone app

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have  error in the last line of the page for the value. what the program do is to count how many click did you click on the screen.

please help me.

I tried to add value as integer and everything but nothing happened before the value there was a problem with savecount then i fix it by adding a privet as integer I think that i solve it in this way.

do you thing that I have to add something with the using stuff ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Threading;


namespace TapToCount
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        private int count;
        private int savedCount;
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
            this.count++;
            this.CountTextBlock.Text = this.count.ToString("N0");
        }
        private void ResetButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.count = 0;
            this.CountTextBlock.Text = this.count.ToString("N0");
        }
        protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);

            // Persist state when leaving for any reason (Deactivated or Closing):
            this.savedCount.value= this.count;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what exception are you getting? How are you trying to save the savedCount field?

Comment: savedCount has any property named value?

Comment: all the idea I want is to count how many time you click the screen in the app

Comment: this error that i get:'int' does not contain a definition for 'value' and no extension method 'value' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1):

`savedCount` is an `int`.  It has no `value` property or field.  Just use

```
this.savedCount = this.count
```

Though I doubt it's going to give you the result you're after.  You probably want to make `savedCount` a static